# JQuery .show() and .hide() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get the below code working for the past 2 hours with no luck. Can anyone see where I am having issues?

Snippet:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.messageBox').hide();
    $('#color').text('');

    $('.color-select-orange').click(function(e) {
        $('.messageBox').show().delay(2000).hide();
        $('#color').text('Orange').show().delay(2000).hide();
    });

});

</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.messageBox').hide();
 $('#color').text('');
 
 $('.color-select-orange').click(function(e) {
        $('.messageBox').show().delay(2000).hide();
  $('#color').text('Orange').show().delay(2000).hide();
    });  
});
```

```css
.messageBox {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 z-index: 100;
  
 padding: 100px;
 
 background-color: #222;
 color: #fff;
 
 font-family: poppins;
 font-size: 14px;
 
 display: block;
}
.messageBox span {
 color: #fff;
 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: poppins;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.customiser {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 position: fixed;
  
 top: 10px;
 left: 0px;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: poppins;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 cursor: pointer;
}



.themes {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 position: relative;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: poppins;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: #222;
 color: #777;
 
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 cursor: pointer;
}
.color-select {
 height: auto;
 width: 100px;
  
 padding: 20px;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: poppins;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: #333;
 color: #777;
}
.color-select:hover {
 background-color: #222;
 color: #fff;
}
.color-select-table {
 width: 100%;
 
 background-color: #222;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.color-select-orange {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ff6e00;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: thin solid #222;
 
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.color-select-orange:hover {
 background-color: #ff6e00;
 color: #fff;
}
.color-select-green {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #9ad749;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: thin solid #222;
 
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.color-select-green:hover {
 background-color: #9ad749;
 color: #fff;
}
.color-select-blue {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #4589f3;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: thin solid #222;
 
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.color-select-blue:hover {
 background-color: #4589f3;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageBox">Theme successfully changed to<br> <span id="color">*SELECTED_COLOUR*</span></div>



<div class="customiser">

<div class="themes">

<div class="color-select">Theme<br>
 
<div class="color-select-table">
 <div class="color-select-orange" onclick="swapStyleSheet('_scripts/default.css')">Orange</div><br>
    <div class="color-select-green" onclick="swapStyleSheet('_scripts/green.css')">Green</div><br>
    <div class="color-select-blue" onclick="swapStyleSheet('_scripts/blue.css')">Blue</div>
</div>

</div><!--END COLOR-SELECT-->

</div><!--END THEMES-->
  
</div><!--END OF CUSTOMISER-->
```

The swapStyleSheet command works fine, but the text change for `#color` and the display change for `.messageBox` does not.

Comment: Any errors in your browsers developer tools console? because the snippet doesn't run even after fixing the obvious errors - if you post a snippet, it should be at least valid syntax - e.g. you have a script tag inside the javascript section, you haven't added jQuery to the snippet, there's no swapStyleSheet function in the code you posted ... those are the obvious errors -

Comment: What's `swapStyleSheet`?

Comment: Where is defined the swapStyleSheet function?

Comment: I would say problem is in the swapStyleSheet function... but what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` are not animated by default, and doesn't support `delay()` as they don't add the the FX queue.

When the delay doesn't work, the elements are hidden right away, and never made visible for two seconds.

To make them animated, one has to pass in a number, and even zero should do it

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.messageBox').hide();
    $('#color').text('');

    $('.color-select-orange').click(function(e) {
        console.log('ds')
        $('.messageBox').show().delay(2000).hide(0);
        $('#color').text('Orange').show().delay(2000).hide(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.messageBox {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: poppins;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.messageBox span {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: poppins;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.customiser {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: poppins;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.themes {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: poppins;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #777;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.color-select {
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: poppins;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #777;
}

.color-select:hover {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

.color-select-table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.color-select-orange {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ff6e00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin solid #222;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.color-select-orange:hover {
    background-color: #ff6e00;
    color: #fff;
}

.color-select-green {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #9ad749;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin solid #222;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.color-select-green:hover {
    background-color: #9ad749;
    color: #fff;
}

.color-select-blue {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #4589f3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin solid #222;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.color-select-blue:hover {
    background-color: #4589f3;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageBox">Theme successfully changed to
    <br> <span id="color">*SELECTED_COLOUR*</span>
</div>
<div class="customiser">
    <div class="themes">
        <div class="color-select">Theme
            <br>
            <div class="color-select-table">
                <div class="color-select-orange">Orange</div>
                <br>
                <div class="color-select-green">Green</div>
                <br>
                <div class="color-select-blue">Blue</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix. Would you know a way to make it animate to drop down or something as such? Im not to advanced in the animation department haha

Comment: `show` and `hide` has a lot of options to slide, fade and what not, **if** you add jQuery UI. Otherwise jQuery does have `slideDown` and `slideUp` to do simple sliding.

Comment: Legend, I may look into adding jQuery UI :)